# Установка нескольких счетчиков (локальный и общий) GA на сайт

Tags: google-analytics

Суть проблемы в следующем, есть 6 сайтов, на каждом из которых стоит отдельный счетчик Google Analytics, нужно добавить на каждый сайт еще один общий счетчик, который будет показывать общую статистику по всем 6 сайтам. Вопрос, как это сделать правильно

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте в тег-менеджере разные теги с триггером по домену сайта, например, а так же один общий с триггером All pages.